# Angular mock $httpBackend give No pending request to flush

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

Following the official guide at [angularJS $httpBackend](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) I'll do this test, but Karma give me this **error**: 
`Error: No pending request to flush !
        at Function.$httpBackend.flush`

**Test**

```
'use strict';

describe('profileCtrl', function () {
var scope, $httpBackend;

beforeEach(angular.mock.module('maap'));
beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope, $controller, _$httpBackend_){

    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $httpBackend.when('GET', 'profile').respond([{id: 1, name: 'Bob'}]);
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $controller('profileCtrl', {$scope: scope});
}))

it('should fetch list of users', function(){
    $httpBackend.flush();
    expectGET(scope.current_user.length).toBe(1);
    expect(scope.current_user[0].name).toBe('Bob');
});
```

});

for this simple **controller**:

```
'use strict';

 angular.module('maap').controller('profileCtrl', function($scope, UserService) {

$scope.current_user = UserService.details(0);
```

});

Comment: is it warning or error?

Comment: @madhured It is an error

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `_$httpBackend_` has nothing to flush because you don't make any http request in your test.

You need to invoke some code that make an http request.

Then, once something somewhere made an http request in your test, you can call the `flush` method so that a response is provided for the request that has been made.

Something like:

```
it('should fetch list of users', function(){

    // Do something that will make an http request
    MyService.getAllUser(function ...) // for example

    // Then provide a response for the http request that 
    // has been made when getAllUser was called
    $httpBackend.flush();

    // Check the expected result.
    expect(something).toBe('Bob');
});
```

Answer (score 12):

Same issue happened to me and the problem was not that I was not making a request but because the request I was making was different to the expected one:

For example I have defined this expectation:

```
mockBackend.expectGET("http://myapi.com/001").respond("RESULT");
```

And I was requesting this other URL:

```
http://myapi.com/002
```

Very confusing error message, no really easily related with the underneath problem.

Comment: same issue here but I can't guess the url I'm requesting. How do you know it? There are a way to show on logs or something?

Comment: Thanks for this, I was trying to figure out why my code wasn't making an http request when it obviously should have been. Turns out I just had a typo in the `expectPOST` url.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, because I neglected to define a response for each expected request. With no response, there becomes nothing to flush. Also the http promise would never resolve or fail.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same exception because I used ngMockE2E module instead of ngMock module. Even calling $rootScope.$digest() didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not using `$http` AngularJs service in your ajax call.

I happened to me where I expected `$httpBackend` to flush something, but I got an error:

> Error: No pending request to flush !

so after a long investigation I found out that the ajax was written in jQuery instead of `$http`

So just make sure that you use `$http` service for your Ajax calls.